# How to locate the element as per the HTML provided?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

```
<a class="action showcart active" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'" href="http://52.14.171.179/xstpl/checkout/cart/">
```

I have tried this one but unable to proceed -

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("cart")).click();
```

Comment: Provided piece of HTML doesn't contain closing tag as well as link text. Update HTML accordingly

Answer (score 0):

As per the HTML you have provided to invoke `click()` the element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("a.action.showcart.active[href='http://52.14.171.179/xstpl/checkout/cart/']"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//a[@class='action showcart active' and @href='http://52.14.171.179/xstpl/checkout/cart/']"))).click();
  ```

Answer (score -1):

```
findElement(By.partialLinkText("cart"))
```

And make sure that the string `"cart"` is case sensitive

Comment: I'm quite sure that there is no such method as `PrtiallinkText()`. Check your answer and update it with correct method

Comment: Could you please give the completed tag like that <a> </a>